# Am I right in database design scheme for mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sharding

I have customers and performers in the system. Customer can create task to do and performers obviously can execute them.

The main problem is that I have to ensure scalability and consistency in the system. And i should design this database in case when every table lies on dedicated server (so I can't do any transactions and joins between this tables).

I think that it would be nice to store operations in one table (let's name it operations table) such as *Create task*, *Execute task*, *Delete task*, *Pay in* and *Pay out* and every user's action which interacts with money (because create task blocks some monies on his acc) will be stored in this table.

And of course we have to make responses for *list of tasks* with offset and *current amount of monies* on user's account. For this two types of request I think we should make some kind of caching tables and there is the main weakness of this schema is that for every request for *table of tasks* and every request for *user money account* we should select last added to operations table for updates in case we lost something.

Am I right in design of database?
Is there any other techniques which helps to avoid non consistent state of distributed database?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are so large each must reside on its own server, that is One Big Database. It would rival anything the NSA might have.

You may get there some day. But in the meantime, at least start down where 99.99% of databases exist.

If you can't have transaction and joins between tables, you also can't have mundane features like foreign key constraints. In a growing database, this spells disaster. For any database, no matter how small or large, the overriding principle that cannot be ignored is data integrity. If you can't maintain that, you'll end up with a whole lot of data and very little information.